# One liner to typedef c structure

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I have a use case where I am trying to typedef a group of structures in various header files

For example, I want to convert this:

```
struct Foo_t
{
   uint8_t one
   uint8_t two;
   uint8_t three;
};
```

To this:

```
typedef struct
{
   uint8_t one
   uint8_t two;
   uint8_t three;
} Foo_t;
```

At a high level I want to use a utility such as sed, awk, or perl to:

1. Find all lines that starts with "struct"
2. Remember the struct tag that follows, in the example above, Foo_t
3. Find the first curly brace "{"
4. Skip n new lines until the first occurrence of the closing bracket
   "}"
5. Insert the struct tag(Foo_t) or whatever that particular stuct is
   called
6. Insert a semicolon to end the struct definition

Unfortunately, the farthest I've got is the following:

```
find . -regextype egrep -path ./dont_touch -prune -o -name "*.h" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/struct* /typedef struct /g;'
```

This approach clearly doesn't work, but it's at least a starting point for me to build on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**Update:**

An example of the test data would be:

*test.h*

```
struct Foo_t
{
   uint8_t one;
   uint8_t two;
   uint8_t three;
   uint8_t four;
};

struct Bar_t
{
   float_t one;
   float_t two;
};

struct Baz_t {
   float_t one;
   float_t two;
};
```

Comment: Will your `struct`s contain (paired) `{` or `}` ? Otherwise, the following should basically work: `perl -0777 -pi -e 's!\bstruct\b\s+(\w+)\s*(\{.*?\})!typedef struct\n$2 $1!s' *.c` (see also [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OuTTgy/1)

Comment: @Corion: I did the same thing, but I have one question. How we can use the captured groups using Perl or Python. Like is there any way to extract above implemented solution using Python ?

Comment: @Deep - I'm using captured groups in Perl above. For Python, you access them as `m = re.search(...); print m.groups(1)` - see [Python regex documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) or post this as a (duplicate) question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the text within your structure definition contains neither `{` nor `}`, the following Perl oneliner will convert all `struct` declarations to `typedef` declarations:

```
perl -0777 -pi -e 's!\bstruct\b\s+(\w+)\s*(\{.*?\})!typedef struct\n$2 $1!sg'
```

`-0777` - slurp the file as a whole into `$_`

`-pi`   - in-place edit the file

`-e`    - using this Perl code

```
s!\bstruct\b\s+(\w+)\s*(\{.*?\})!typedef struct\n$2 $1!sg
```

Replace all `struct` followed by a C identifier and then `{` ... `}` by `typedef struct`, then the braces and stuff and then the identifier. See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OuTTgy/1) for details.

#### See also

[perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) - for the explanation of the regex parts

[perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) - for the command line switches

Comment: This is extremely helpful. And thank you for that link to the regex site! One odd thing I noticed, if I have more than 1 struct in the header, the perl command only modifies the first struct. I added a test file to my question for demonstration. In the example above, I used your command and passed test.h containing the 3 struct definitions mentioned above. perl -0777 -pi -e 's!\bstruct\b\s+(\w+)\s*(\{.*?\})!typedef struct\n$2 $1!s' test.h. I'm guessing I just need a "global" argument of sorts so that all structs in that file are operated on?

Comment: Awesome. Works like a charm. Thanks!